# Perpendicular axis theorem on a particle

Tags: classical-mechanics

Is perpendicular axis theorem (inertia) applicable to a particle?

If no, Why not?

If yes, then in the question 
**A uniform circular disc has diameter AB, mass 2m and radius a. A particle of mass m is attached to the disc at B. The disc is able to rotate about a smooth fixed horizontal axis through A. The axis tangential to the disc. Show that the moment of inertia of the system about the axis is 13/2 ma^2.**

Why is perpendicular axis theorem not used on the particle?

Comment: Why would you need to apply it to the particle?

Comment: Well because the particle is also going to be rotate about the tangential axis.

Comment: You just need to find the MI of the disc about the tangent (for which you do need the perpendicular axes and parallel axes theorems) and add the MI of the particle

Comment: Yes but why does the perpendicular axis theorem not apply for the particle?

Comment: In a trivial sense, it does, but the MI of the particle about any axis through the particle is zero

Comment: Oh so basically we do apply the perpendicular axis theorem but since it's negligible we assume it to 0 and go on to calculate the shifted inertia.

Comment: Actually you really don't have to apply the perpendicular axis theorem to the particle at all, only the disc.